# What is the execution sequence of javascript async?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following angular code

```
// 1.
var something = 0;
// 2.
something = 1;

$http.get('some_url')
  .then(function() {
  // 3.
    something = 2;
  })
  .catch(function(){})

// 4.
something = 3

// 5.
something = 4

// 6.
$http.get('some_url')
```

Say that after statement `4`, the `$http` resolves

Does statement `5` get to execute next or does statement `3` get to execute next?

If statement `5` get to execute next does it mean that it will continue to execute subsequent statements until the thread is not in used?

If statement `3` get to execute next does it mean that the thread always get interrupted by the promise resolving using the time of the call order?

What is the general rule of ordering, and are there exceptions for other more complex situation, like nested promise etc?

Comment: Your question doesn't really makes sense. If 3 finishes first, it's first. If 5 finishes first, it's first. Are you asking what happens if they finish at exactly the same time?

Comment: Did you run and and see what happens?

Comment: cosole.log() is your friend

Comment: javascript is executing in a single thread. `$http.get` is an async operation, the callback will be called after all other operations. So the execution order will be: 
1
2
4
5
3

Comment: @jordaniac89 My usage of word first is not correct, I think what I meant is which statement goes next.

Comment: @alexmac Thanks for the answer, although what if I have two promises resolve at the same time? Does the call order of the promise matters?

Comment: @epascarello I couldn't get the promise to resolve exactly when statement 4 finishes using $time or $interval

Comment: No it doesn't matter. I repeat js is single threaded, two or more promises or any async operations can't be resolved at the same time. Only one by one.

Comment: @alexmac I see, so I imagine when the server returns the result of the get call, the result get put into a queue somewhere that the javascript will process only if the thread is free?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: @alexmac That make sense, thanks :)

Comment: there is no general rule of ordering with asynchronous operations... that's why you use promises and why promise chains are common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While javascript uses an asynchronous event loop, javascript code execution is serial, and completely deterministic. Your code will execute in this order:

1. something = 0
2. something = 1
3. $http.get('some_url')
4. something = 3
5. something = 4
6. $http.get('some_url')

After step 6 is where the execution can diverge. The code will wait until one of the http requests has completed, then resolve the promise for that request, which subsequently runs the function in your `then` statement. (2 requests cannot resolve at the same time since javascript executes in serial, as previously stated)

To answer your question directly, *code execution cannot be interrupted in javascript*. When a function is executed, it runs until it returns. Any asynchronous operations that complete during that time will only be able to run after the function returns. Multiple possible events like the one above are executed in "first in first out" order of when they are triggered.